# How to clip output of CNN to specific list of colours

Tags: python, tensorflow, colors, deep-learning, style-transfer

Typical image GAN has output of shape `(w,h,3)` with values 0...1 that are then scaled to 0...255 to represent coloured image.

So in each w,h position we get 3 values that together represent single colour in RGB space.

I want to somehow limit that output to allow only specific colours as output. For example

```
colours = [[200, 20, 20], [20, 200, 20], [20, 20, 200], ...] 
number_of_allowed_colours = len(colours)
```

Ideally the allowed colours would be a part of input but given the complexity of task I am ok with starting first iterations of network with colours as part of network architecture.

So far I have unsuccessfully tried many approaches. The way I see it could be accomplished is having the last layer of network be of shape `(w,h,number_of_allowed_colours)` and then activation function is applied so that to map that 3rd dimension to corresponding colour triplet. One idea I am trying to expand is using something like `tf.argmax` in combination with `tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable`. Another option I am looking into is having the regular `(w,h,3)` shape layer but within activation round it up to closest match in colour. The problem here is the lack of gradient and the fact that there are no perfect algoritm to compare colours.

Edited: The loss function have to use the generated output image thus the solution has to fully differentiable. The output of network has to be `(w,h,3)` shaped image.

Comment: have you tried `tf.clip_by_value` ?

Comment: Don't see how I could use it. I have several possible allowed colours while clip_by_value have only min and max. Or am I missing a use cases here?

Comment: I would go for the first option. However, I would keep the mapping to the original space of colors out of the network, as this would require using non-differentiable operations. You would need to transform your labels to the discrete format and use those to train the network. During prediction time, you can always transform the network's output to the pixel format.

Comment: @rvinas The problem here is that the loss function that I want to apply have to use the end image by applying pre-trained classification network like VGG and extracting features from output image. So the real struggle here is coming up with something that is differentiable (and in a way there is general question - is that even reliably possible). I will edit question with this note.

Comment: I see. Let `out` be the output tensor of your current network, with shape `(w, h, number_of_allowed_colours)`. Then, what you could do is the following: convert the list `colours` into a tensor of shape `(number_of_allowed_colours, 3)` and perform a tensor multiplication `tensor_dot(out, colours)` to map the output tensor back to `(w, h, 3)` and use this to compute your loss. The resulting tensor will be a linear combination of the different colours (differentiable!) - you can then use a regularization term to encourage sparsity in tensor `out`.

Comment: How big is your `allowed_colours` list? Is it in 10s, 100s, etc?

Comment: number of allowed colours would be between 10...100 but most likely around 20

Comment: @rvinas Not entirely sure I understood your idea. I see how `tensordot(out, colours)` could produce shape of `(w,h,3)` but the values would be different than the ones in `colours` list. Unless you propose to convert the `out` tto be 0,1 digits in it's last dimension. Not sure if that's possible to do that?

Comment: That's right, the values might be different than the ones in `colours`. But by applying some sparsity regularization (or softmax temperature) to `out` you can hopefully make them as close to `colours` as possible. The thing is that it is not possible to map your discrete representation to the continuous one (e.g. through `tf.argmax`) without breaking backpropagation - if you want it to be differentiable, you need some sort of continuous approximation.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to know if this will actually work, but the suggestions below make your concepts differentiable.

> `(w,h,number_of_allowed_colours)` and then activation function is applied so that to map that 3rd dimension to corresponding colour triplet. One idea I am trying to expand is using something like `tf.argmax` in combination with `tf.contrib.lookup.HashTable`. Another option I am looking into is having the regular `(w,h,3)`

I think you're really close here. You just need to make these operations differentiable.

For the first one, where you said:

> activation function is applied ... `tf.argmax` ... `lookup.HashTable`.

What you want to do here looks a lot like an attention layer.
Use `activation="softmax"` to get a weighted distribution over colors, where the weights sum to one. Take the weighted average of the colors.

> Another option I am looking into is having the regular (w,h,3) but within activation round it up to closest match in colour. The problem here is the lack of gradient and the fact that there are no perfect algoritm to compare colours.

Again you've got the right idea, and are just missing a few details to make it differentiable. Here again I think you might just need a weighting that sums to one. You could get that by for each point, calculating the distance to each color-option and then taking `softmax(-r**2)` across the options. That way close options get a high weight, and distant options get weighted towards zero.

### Averaging colors:

Don't forget [gamma correction](http://www.ericbrasseur.org/gamma.html?i=1).

Comment: Could you explain what you meant with `softmax(-r**2)`? softmax itself gives as "weighting that sums to one" but what [and why] is the parameter r?

Comment: The distance from the prediction to each option in your list. Clarified the answer a little (i hope)